# How to migrate msdb from SQL Server to Azure SQL database?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I want to migrate system database `msdb` to an Azure SQL database. Currently, Azure SQL database is not supporting `msdb`. Is there any alternative to migrate or any other approaches?

Comment: msdb is a system database. What's in there that you want to migrate?

Comment: Please consider SQL Azure Managed Instance.  it supports more of the traditional SQL Server artifacts and may meet your needs

Comment: Why you need to migrate MSDB? Are you interested in jobs, operators, packages, maintenance plans? What MSDB contains that you are missing on Azure SQL?